# TCPClient disconnects after several hours

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, tcpclient

I've created a Windows service that waits for TCPClient connections and relays any messages to all connected clients (except the sender). My code is based on [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-Multi-User-TCPIP-43cc3b44) example.

One client connects when an event is triggered, sends some progress updates and then disconnects. The other clients are front end applications that receive and display the update.

If these clients are left idle for several hours they seem to loose the connection without any error\warning. I cannot find any relevent timouts for idle periods, is there something I am missing?

Service Code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    _Listener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1314)
    _Listener.Start()
    ListenForClient()
    _ConnectionMontior = Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf DoMonitorConnections, New MonitorInfo(_Listener, _Connections), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
End Sub

Private Sub ListenForClient()
    Dim info As New ConnectionInfo(_Listener)
    _Listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AddressOf DoAcceptClient, info)
End Sub

Private Sub DoAcceptClient(result As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        Dim monitorInfo As MonitorInfo = CType(_ConnectionMontior.AsyncState, MonitorInfo)
    If monitorInfo.Listener IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not monitorInfo.Cancel Then
        Dim info As ConnectionInfo = CType(result.AsyncState, ConnectionInfo)
        monitorInfo.Connections.Add(info)
        info.AcceptClient(result)
        ListenForClient()
        info.AwaitData()
    End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteToEventLog("DoAcceptClient: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub DoMonitorConnections()

    Try

        'Create delegate for updating output display
        ' Dim doAppendOutput As New Action(Of String)(AddressOf AppendOutput)

        'Get MonitorInfo instance from thread-save Task instance
        Dim monitorInfo As MonitorInfo = CType(_ConnectionMontior.AsyncState, MonitorInfo)

        'Implement client connection processing loop
        Do
            'Create temporary list for recording closed connections
            Dim lostConnections As New List(Of ConnectionInfo)

            'Examine each connection for processing
            For Each info As ConnectionInfo In monitorInfo.Connections
                If info.Client.Connected Then
                    'Process connected client
                    If info.DataQueue.Count > 0 Then
                        'The code in this If-Block should be modified to build 'message' objects
                        'according to the protocol you defined for your data transmissions.
                        'This example simply sends all pending message bytes to the output textbox.
                        'Without a protocol we cannot know what constitutes a complete message, so
                        'with multiple active clients we could see part of client1's first message,
                        'then part of a message from client2, followed by the rest of client1's
                        'first message (assuming client1 sent more than 64 bytes).
                        Dim messageBytes As New List(Of Byte)
                        While info.DataQueue.Count > 0
                            messageBytes.Add(info.DataQueue.Dequeue)
                        End While

                        'Relay the message to all clients except the sender
                        For Each inf As ConnectionInfo In monitorInfo.Connections
                            If inf.Client.Connected Then
                                Dim msg As String = info.Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString & "|" & System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageBytes.ToArray)
                                If Not inf.Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString = msg.Split("|")(0) Then
                                    inf.Client.Client.Send(messageBytes.ToArray)
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next

                    End If
                Else
                    'Record clients no longer connected
                    lostConnections.Add(info)
                End If
            Next

            'Clean-up any closed client connections
            If lostConnections.Count > 0 Then
                While lostConnections.Count > 0
                    monitorInfo.Connections.Remove(lostConnections(0))
                    lostConnections.RemoveAt(0)
                End While
            End If

            'Throttle loop to avoid wasting CPU time
            _ConnectionMontior.Wait(1)
        Loop While Not monitorInfo.Cancel

        'Close all connections before exiting monitor
        For Each info As ConnectionInfo In monitorInfo.Connections
            info.Client.Close()
        Next
        monitorInfo.Connections.Clear()

    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteToEventLog("DoMonitorConnections" & ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Client Code:

```
 _ServerAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP)
 _Connection = New ConnectionInfo(_ServerAddress, 1314, AddressOf InvokeAppendOutput)
 _Connection.AwaitData()
```

ConnectionInfo Class:

```
Public Class ConnectionInfo
Private _AppendMethod As Action(Of String)
Public ReadOnly Property AppendMethod As Action(Of String)
    Get
        Return _AppendMethod
    End Get
End Property

Private _Client As TcpClient
Public ReadOnly Property Client As TcpClient
    Get
        Return _Client
    End Get
End Property

Private _Stream As NetworkStream
Public ReadOnly Property Stream As NetworkStream
    Get
        Return _Stream
    End Get
End Property

Private _LastReadLength As Integer
Public ReadOnly Property LastReadLength As Integer
    Get
        Return _LastReadLength
    End Get
End Property

Private _Buffer(255) As Byte

Public Sub New(address As IPAddress, port As Integer, append As Action(Of String))
    _AppendMethod = append
    _Client = New TcpClient
    _Client.Connect(address, port)
    _Stream = _Client.GetStream
End Sub

Public Sub AwaitData()
    _Stream.BeginRead(_Buffer, 0, _Buffer.Length, AddressOf DoReadData, Me)
End Sub

Public Sub Close()
    If _Client IsNot Nothing Then _Client.Close()
    _Client = Nothing
    _Stream = Nothing
End Sub

Private Const MESSAGE_DELIMITER As Char = ControlChars.Cr
Dim sBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder

Private Sub DoReadData(result As IAsyncResult)

    Dim info As ConnectionInfo = CType(result.AsyncState, ConnectionInfo)

    Try
        If info._Stream IsNot Nothing AndAlso info._Stream.CanRead Then
            info._LastReadLength = info._Stream.EndRead(result)
            If info._LastReadLength > 0 Then
                Dim message As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(info._Buffer, 0, info._LastReadLength)


                If (message.IndexOf(MESSAGE_DELIMITER) > -1) Then

                    Dim subMessages() As String = message.Split(MESSAGE_DELIMITER)

                    sBuilder.Append(subMessages(0))
                    If Not info._Client.Client.LocalEndPoint.ToString = sBuilder.ToString.Split("|")(0) Then
                        info._AppendMethod(sBuilder.ToString)
                    End If

                    sBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder

                    If subMessages.Length = 2 Then
                        sBuilder.Append(subMessages(1))
                    Else
                        For i As Integer = 1 To subMessages.GetUpperBound(0) - 1
                            'MessageBox.Show(subMessages(i))
                            info._AppendMethod(subMessages(i))
                        Next
                        sBuilder.Append(subMessages(subMessages.GetUpperBound(0)))
                    End If
                Else
                    sBuilder.Append(message)
                End If
            End If
        End If

        info.AwaitData()

    Catch ex As Exception
        info._LastReadLength = -1
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP does not guarantee that a side not trying to send data can detect a loss of the connection. You should have taken this into account when you designed your application protocol.

What you are seeing is most commonly caused by NAT or stateful firewalls. As a practical matter, if you don't send data at least every ten minutes, you can expect at least some clients to get disconnected. Their NAT devices or stateful firewalls simply forget about the connection. Neither side notices until it tries to send data.

I would suggest creating some kind of dummy message that the server sends to all its clients every five minutes. Basically, this is just some small chunk of data that can be uniquely identified as serving only to keep the connection alive.

Each client responds to the dummy message by sending a dummy message back to the server. If a client doesn't receive a dummy message in ten minutes, it should consider the connection lost, close it, and try to connect again.

The mere act of trying to send the dummy message will cause the server to detect any lost connections, but you should probably also consider as dead any connection to a client that hasn't responded to a dummy message by the time you're ready to send the next one. The client will know a connection is lost when it doesn't receive the dummy message. The exchange of messages will keep the NAT/firewall entry alive.